# when i use dataType json it shows elment ] is missing in my ajax script

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

trying to use datatype json to get the value in json format but when i add  it into my script it shows error that elemet ] is missing what am i doing wrong?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');

        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && lastID != 0){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',

                url:'<?php echo base_url("user/get_all_post"); ?>',
                data:"id="+lastID,
                dataType:'json',

                beforeSend:function(html){
                    $('.load-more').show();
                },
                success:function(html){

                 //alert(html);
                 var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(html);            
              var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);
              //alert(json);
            /*
              var json =" [{'id':1,'name':'Test1'},{'id':2,'name':'Test2'}]";
              var jsonArray = eval('(' + json + ')');
            for (i in jsonArray)
            {
             alert(jsonArray[i]["name"]);
            }
            */
             // alert(json.id);
              var jsonArray = eval('(' + json + ')');

             $PostId=jsonArray[4]["id"];
           // alert($PostId);

            for(i in jsonArray)
            {
            $post_status=jsonArray[i]["status"];
            $status_image=jsonArray[i]["status_image"];
            $multimage=jsonArray[i]["multimage"];

              //alert(Lastid);

              //alert($post_status);
              //alert($status_image);
              //alert($multimage);

                  $('.load-more').attr('lastID',$PostId);
                  $('#result_table').append(jsonArray);

                     }
                 } 
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

i want to access my json data so that i can display it but all the variable shows undefined when i access then in my view

Comment: seems odd to take a javascript object returned by `$.ajax` ... turn it into JSON, turn it back to an object, then use `eval` !! you'll find `html` is a plain ol' javascript object you can use like any other ... you var `json` is an object ... `var jsonArray = eval('(' + json + ')');` will not be anything useful at all

Comment: when i alert thes values $post_status the data is there but when i try to access them in my html it shows undefined variable

Comment: If you use `datatype:json` you need to send `data` as `json object` like `data:{"id":lastID},`

Comment: still shows missing element @Mairaj

Comment: Do you get in `error` or `success` in `ajax` ?

Comment: success the value is passing and shows in firebug response

Comment: do this: `success:function(jsonArray){` and remove the stringify/parse/eval garbage - i.e. remove everything between that and the line above `$PostId=jsonArray[4]["id"];` - e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/9yLxfx8d/

Comment: this is working but still no values are passing to the $('#result_table').append(jsonArray); @JaromandaX

Comment: i can get the values of the json to show in the response but no value are showing in the id "result_table" @JaromandaX

Comment: You are passing data wrongly to post call, you should pass it as JSON. Is the error coming in ajax success call ?

Comment: how am i sending it wrongly? can you explain? @subrahmanyabhat

Comment: no there is no error

Comment: i just cant pass the data to the html element'

Comment: when i alert($post_status) it shows the value but when i try to send it to "result_table" it shows nothing @subrahmanyabhat

Comment: Is that response coming to success function ?

Comment: yes @subrahmanyabhat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution for this i was just adding everything in my code where i just needed to access my json value for that i only needed to parse the json value and then i can access the array in for loop 
hope it helps other too

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var lastID = $('.load-more').attr('lastID');

        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() && lastID != 0){
            jQuery.ajax({
                type:'POST',

                url:'<?php echo base_url("user/get_all_post"); ?>',
                 data: "id=" + lastID,
                    dataType: 'json', 


                beforeSend:function(html){
                    $('.load-more').show();
                },
                success:function(data){
                       var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);            
                       var json = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);

                        $PostId=json[4]['id'];


                        for(i as json)
                      {

                            var post_status = json[i]['status'];
                            $status_image = json[i]['status_image'];
                            var multimage = json[i]['multimage'];

                                       alert($status_image);               
                             $("#status_data").append('<div style=" margin: 20px 50px 0px 40px; ">'+'<a>'+'<?php echo img($user_image); ?>'  +'</a>'+'<a>'+ ' <?php echo $uname; ?>' +'</a>'+'<div>'+post_status+'</div>' +'</div>');

                             $("#status_data").append('<div style=" margin: 20px 50px 0px 40px; ">'+'<a>'+'<?php echo img($user_image); ?>'  +'</a>'+'<a>'+ ' <?php echo $uname; ?>' +'</a>'+'<div>'+'<img src="'+<?php base_url('uploads/'); ?> status_image+'">'+'</div>' +'</div>');
                      }
           $('.load-more').attr('lastID', $PostId);
                    }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

this would work there is no need for eval or jsonArray. thanks to everyone for replying.

Answer (score 0):

first, your `user/get_all_post` need to return json data (and also have response header with `application/json`)

use `output` class
(ref. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html)

```
$this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode(array('foo' => 'bar')));
```

then you can use json attribute in jquery when it response

```
success:function(response){
  alert(response.foo)
}
```